# How do i install ubuntu on a Chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I'm wondering how to install Ubuntu on my Chromebook? And what other steps should be taken?

Matt

Comment: did you encounter any errors or issues

Comment: @MattDewell, If you are satisfied I would greatly appreciate if you could set my answer as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** You can't (In most cases). Especially if your Chromebook is a school or company issued Chromebook.

**Long Answer:** If your Chromebook that you wish is NOT part of a Corporate/Education system then you can look into these options:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**ChrUbuntu:** [ChrUbuntu](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.fr/) is a Ubuntu system built for Chromebooks. It works like a traditional dual-boot system. You can restart your Chromebook and choose between Chrome OS and Ubuntu at boot time. ChrUbuntu can be installed on your Chromebook’s internal storage or on a USB device or SD card.

**Crouton:** [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) actually uses a “chroot” environment to run both Chrome OS and Ubuntu at the same time. Ubuntu runs alongside Chrome OS, so you can switch between Chrome OS and your standard Linux desktop environment with a keyboard shortcut. This gives you the ability to take advantage of both environments without any rebooting needed. Crouton allows you to use Chrome OS while having a standard Linux environment with all its command-line tools and desktop applications a few keystrokes away.

There are plenty of "How-To's" out there right now but I suggest you look [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/795730-how-to-easily-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-with-crouton).

**NOTE:** A further explanation about why you CANNOT install ANY type of 3rd party Linux software on a Chrombook of workplace or school facility:

I know this from first hand experience and hours of attempting and failing. All Chromebooks that are purchased by a company or an organization is given a Control Panel that gives the IT Staff the ability to block/disable specific functions of the Chromebook. **BY DEFAULT** the Control Panel is set to block your access to the part of the developer console required to install Linux.

There is a way around this, but it requires you to remove the bottom of your Chromebook. You then flip a switch that can be located on different locations on your Chromebook depending on the Model/Version. That switch will then essentially "hard reset" your Chromebook. Doing this however will void ANY warranty. Not to mention if you are not familiar with Linux, the risk of "Bricking" your Chromebook becomes dangerously high.